# How can I validate multi-select inputs and textareas using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, validation

I am working with jQuery form validation, but right now I am unable to put validation on multiple-select dropdowns and textareas. How can I validate these fields using jQuery?

Here is my HTML code:

```
<select id="demo-multiple-select3" multiple name="model_type2[]">
    <option value="1">Type 1</option>
    <option value="2">Type 2</option>
    <option value="3">Type 3</option>
</select>

<textarea id="editor" name="description"></textarea>
```

Here is my script code,Thank you in advance.

```
$("#myform").validate({
           rules: {
            nft_name: "required",  
            description: "required",
            model_type2: "required",            
            },
           messages: {
                nft_name: "Please enter NFT name",
                description: "Please enter description",
                model_type2: "Please select model_type2"
            },
            errorPlacement: function(error, element) 
       });
```

Answer (score 0):

Name has to be defined in jQuery validator.

```
      $("#myform").validate({
           rules: {
            nft_name: "required",  
            description: "required",
            'model_type2[]': "required",            
            },
           messages: {
                nft_name: "Please enter NFT name",
                description: "Please enter description",
                'model_type2[]': "Please select model_type2"
            },
            errorPlacement: function(error, element) 
       });
```

Comment: Why should the OP ___try this___? **Good answers** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way,
not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO that may find this question and be reading your answer. If it is well answered maybe they will UpVote it.

Comment: @Paras Raiyani: sorry but its not working